# how can I add the (*) between entered numbers with scanf Function?

Tags: c

the number which is entered with scanf function ,between all of the figures should be putted * as much as the value of the figure.

example output

Please enter an integer:1324

1*3***2**4****

Comment: Any attempts so far?

Comment: It's not quite clear what your question is currently. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]

Comment: The number we entered is not certain, so I could not think how to set the digits of the number we enter.

Comment: Rather than inputting an integer, input a string. Then, for each character, print the character (you may want to validate first) and as many stars as needed. Otherwise an easy solution using integer is to recurse... (`recurse(n/10);`)

Comment: ı have to use integer,ım searching on it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take input as string and for each character of string(suppose, s[i]) print `*` character, *`s[i]-'0'` times*. See the implementation below for better understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[100000];
    printf("Please enter an integer:");
    scanf("%s", s);
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        printf("%c", s[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < s[i]-'0'; j++){
            printf("*");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to do it only by using integer, you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m, a, i;
    printf("Please enter an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    m = 1;
    while(m < n){
        m *= 10;
    }
    m /= 10;
    while(n != 0){
        a = n/m;
        n %= m;
        m /= 10;
        printf("%d", a);
        for(i = 0; i < a; i++){
            printf("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir,it's working..now ım searching for it to understand.

Comment: len = strlen(s)

 and what is that ? we did not learn something like this :/,

is that a function in string.h library ?

Comment: Yes it's a function in string.h library which return the length of a string, example if char s[] = "asde23", then strlen(s) is equl to 6.

Comment: oh ım sorry,ı did not learn that.ı cant use it ..ı have to find different solution with integer..what can ı do,what you advice to me ?

Comment: It's ok. I added a new code in my answer. hope it will be useful. Happy coding

Comment: for n!=0, ,code is not working. for n >=0,it is working :)

programme is not show to output 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's both a string and an integer (using `atoi()`) implementation

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sprint(const char *i) {
    while (isdigit((unsigned char)*i)) {
        putchar(*i);
        for (int k = 0; k < *i - '0'; k++) putchar('*');
        i++;
    }
}

void iprint(int i) {
    if (i > 9) iprint(i/10);
    putchar(i % 10 + '0');
    for (int k = 0; k < i % 10; k++) putchar('*');
}

int main(void) {
    char in[99];
    while (fgets(in, 99, stdin)) {
        sprint(in);
        printf(" ---- ");
        iprint(atoi(in));
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/vFY1I8